# Openshift cluster - Github webhook not working

Tags: openshift, webhooks

I have an openshift cluster with a build config and Git web hook configured. I click on "copy webhook with Secret"

[image]

Then I go to my public github repo > Settings > Webhook and I add the webhook as per below (the secret is correct in the webhook url)
[image]

However when I commit some code, the webhook is not working with error: "We couldn’t deliver this payload: failed to connect".
I googled the issue but could not find anything relating to Openshift. Any idea please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you specify the URL of an **internal** OpenShift cluster. GitHub does not know what that URL is, as it is an internal URL that is not publically available. That is the most likely reason you receive "failed to connect". You should provide an URL that is publically accessible.

So you'll need to have external access (from the internet) to your cluster, that is something your OpenShift administrators can maybe help you with.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Do you know what I need to ask the admins specifically? What feature or command to enable?
Thanks

Comment: I guess "Is our cluster accessible via the internet? Can this be configured?" would be a good question.